# Download file from server using a command line

Tags: wget

I have 2 different servers, I put my mp3 files in **server1**, and I am testing to download them from **server2** using the wget tool:

```
wget "http://www.example.com/Path-to-mp3-file"
```

I have 2 results:

1) If I download from server1 (where files are), it downloads

2) If I download from server2, it says 404

```
wget "http://www.example.com/Path-to-mp3-file"
--2016-06-15 10:08:06--  http://www.example.com/Path-to-mp3-file
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... SERVER2-IP
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|SERVER2-IP|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-06-15 10:08:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

**EDIT**

I place the -o filename.mp3 and I can download it now, what is the difference between both commands:

```
wget "http://www.example.com/Path-to-mp3-file"
```

and

```
wget -o filename.mp3 "http://www.example.com/Path-to-mp3-file"
```

Comment: This question currently seems to boil down to "*when I try to download files from a server which doesn't have them, I get a 404*".  If that's the case, why on earth are you surprised?  If it's not, could you clarify the question?

Comment: The file exists on the server, files are in server1, using wget command line on server1, the file is downloaded, using the same command from server2, it gives 404 ** [EDIT:  I edit my command line using 'wget -o file.mp3 URL', and now it works, how come without specifying the -o file.mp3 from remote server, does not download?] **

Comment: You say the file exists **on server1**, but you can't download it **from server2**.  This is not odd (modulo some shared or sync'ed storage that you've not mentioned).  If something odd *is* happening, your question should reflect that.  If you're changing it, by the way, please **update the question**; adding content in comments isn't the best way to refine a question.